# Cyclic vectors of an irreducible representation of a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a C*-algebra and $(H,\pi)$ an irreducible representation of $\mathcal{A}$.

I want to prove the statement:  all $\xi \in H$ are cyclic or $\pi(\mathcal{A})=\{0\}$ and $H=\mathbb{C}$.

How can one approach this problem?

Suppose there is a $\hat{\xi}\in H$ that is not cyclic, then $\{a\hat\xi:a\in \pi(\mathcal{A})\}$ is not dense in H, i.e. $\{a\hat\xi:a\in \pi(\mathcal{A})\}^{\perp}\neq \{0\}$. From here on, I don't know how to conclude that $\pi(\mathcal{A})=\{0\}$ and $H=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Any vector $\xi$ generates a subrepresentation. By irreducibility, $\xi$ must be cyclic, unless your representation is trivial or one dimensional. (A one dimensional rep is automatically irreducible.)

Comment: Thanks! What do you exactly mean with "$\xi$ generates a subrepresentation"?

Comment: Welcome. Just by your formula: consider the Hilbert subspace generated by $\{\pi(a)\xi, a \in A \}$. This is by construction an invariant subspace of $\pi(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement to be proven should be slightly modified as follows.

> **Proposition:** Let $ \mathcal{A} $ be a C*-algebra and $ (\mathcal{H},\pi) $ an irreducible *-representation of $ \mathcal{A} $. Then either
>
> - each $ \xi \in \mathcal{H} \setminus \{ 0_{\mathcal{H}} \} $ is a cyclic vector, or
> - $ \pi[\mathcal{A}] = \{ 0_{B(\mathcal{H})} \} $ and $ \mathcal{H} \cong \mathbb{C} $.

*Proof*

If each $ \xi \in \mathcal{H} \setminus \{ 0_{\mathcal{H}} \} $ is already a cyclic vector, then there is nothing to show.

Hence, suppose that there is a $ \xi \in \mathcal{H} \setminus \{ 0_{\mathcal{H}} \} $ that is not a cyclic vector. By definition, this means that
$$
\mathcal{H}' ~ \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} ~
\overline{\{ [\pi(a)](\xi) ~|~ a \in \mathcal{A} \}}^{\| \cdot \|_{\mathcal{H}}}
$$
is a closed and proper linear subspace of $ \mathcal{H} $. Clearly, $ \mathcal{H}' $ is also an invariant subspace of $ (\mathcal{H},\pi) $. As $ (\mathcal{H},\pi) $ is irreducible, we have $ \mathcal{H}' = \{ 0_{\mathcal{H}} \} $, which means that $ [\pi(a)](\xi) = 0_{\mathcal{H}} $ for each $ a \in \mathcal{A} $. It follows that the one-dimensional linear subspace $ \mathbb{C} \cdot \xi \subseteq \mathcal{H} $ is an invariant subspace of $ (\mathcal{H},\pi) $; to see this, simply observe that
\begin{align}
\forall a \in \mathcal{A}: \quad
           [\pi(a)][\mathbb{C} \cdot \xi]
&=         \mathbb{C} \cdot [\pi(a)](\xi) \\
&=         \mathbb{C} \cdot 0_{\mathcal{H}} \\
&=         \{ 0_{\mathcal{H}} \} \\
&\subseteq \mathbb{C} \cdot \xi.
\end{align}
By the irreducibility of $ (\mathcal{H},\pi) $ again, we thus obtain
$$
\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{C} \cdot \xi \cong \mathbb{C}.
$$
Therefore, $ [\pi(a)][\mathcal{H}] = \{ 0_{\mathcal{H}} \} $ for each $ a \in \mathcal{A} $, which immediately yields
$$
\pi[\mathcal{A}] = \{ 0_{B(\mathcal{H})} \}. \quad \blacksquare
$$

Comment: It seems that we don't even need much algebraic structure on $\mathcal A$ for the proof. Does the statement remain true if we assume $\mathcal A$ is only a group, and $\pi$ an irreducible representation of $\mathcal A$ as a group?